# Problem with Mongo DB using Mongoid Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm developing on Ubuntu, I have installed the mongoid gem, and when I run the rails server, I get this error

```
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:518:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

I remembered using a command like brew install but I am pretty clueless. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have MongoDB installed, too. Since you're on Ubuntu, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

If you saw any `brew` commands in any instructions you were reading, those were likely for Homebrew on Mac OS X, not for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

other possibility
 you didnt start the server(which should auto-start usually)

mongod also has this weirdness

try to run sudo mongod in a foreground process
and the messages should tell you how to recover